# Elasticsearch SignatureDoesNotMatch error when creating snapshot on GCS using s3

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm running elasticsearch 2.3.0 with installed cloud-aws plugin.
I'm trying to create snapshot on Google Cloud Storage using the cloud-aws plugin knowing that Google storage is compatible with S3.

I followed this documentation
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating#keys

for the so called "Migration" part.

Unfortunately I'm getting this error:
`Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch`

Here the rest call I'm sending:

```
curl -XPUT http://XXX:9200/_snapshot/google-test-repo -d '{
    "type": "s3",
    "settings": {
        "endpoint": "storage.googleapis.com",
        "bucket": "/my-bucket",
        "base_path": "mydirectory",
        "access_key": "my-google-dev-key",
        "secret_key": "my-google-secret-key"
    }
}'
```

Ad this is the response:

```
   {
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "repository_verification_exception",
        "reason": "[google-test-repo] path [mydirectory] is not accessible on master node"
      }
    ],
    "type": "repository_verification_exception",
    "reason": "[google-test-repo] path [mydirectory] is not accessible on master node",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "i_o_exception",
      "reason": "Unable to upload object mydirectory/tests-C4S-4T6FS1CIMkvjebOMBw/master.dat-temp",
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "amazon_s3_exception",
        "reason": "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch; Request ID: null)"
      }
    }
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was resolved by providing the appropriate **Signer Type**

Snapshot creation tries to do a PUT request and thus fails with the above error. Once you add the below given line in elasticsearch.yml config file, the error should go away. Please note that you need to restart the elasticsearch service after any change in the yml file.

```
cloud.aws.s3.signer: S3SignerType
```

Refer : https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-cloud-aws/issues/223